# Every semisimple ring is fusible

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory, modules

Every semisimple ring is fusible.

How should I start to show that. This is in a paper I am reading now. But it says this is clear. I have no idea how to show that.

Comment: Please include all necessary definitions from the paper. I suppose you are talking about [this paper](https://www.google.at/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=2ahUKEwimgYue9rLzAhXPh_0HHR0-BZwQFnoECAwQAQ&url=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.tandfonline.com%2Fdoi%2Fabs%2F10.1080%2F00927872.2016.1206347&usg=AOvVaw0Mpso-IgxFZhkH64_JlJ9p).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Every semisimple ring is unit regular (it is a well known),on the other hand,
every unit regular ring is left fusible(See Proposition 2.13. Every unit-regular ring is left fusible. (see for a proof in the paper:
On fusible rings
M. Tamer Koşan & Jerzy Matczuk
M. Tamer Koşan & Jerzy Matczuk (2019) On fusible rings, Communications in
Algebra, 47:9, 3789-3793, DOI: 10.1080/00927872.2019.1570236
To link to this article: https://doi.org/10.1080/00927872.2019.1570236))